# How to change text leading in node

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

My goal is to get text in a node closer.

Here is how it should be done:
Look at XXXXXXXXXXX node.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}%
\mode<presentation>%
{
\usetheme{Madrid}%
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\makeatletter
   \newcommand\myFont{\@setfontsize\myFont{6pt}{7}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  arrows,%
  shapes.misc,%
  shapes.arrows,%
  positioning,% wg. " of "
  scopes,%
  decorations.pathmorphing,%
  shadows%
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\title[Example]%
{\textbf{How to get better leading in node}} %
\subtitle{}%
\author[]%
{Foo Bar}%
\institute[of Beamer]%
{ 
%
}
\date[\today]%
{}%

\subject{Talks}%

\definecolor{niebieski}{HTML}{aac9cb}
\definecolor{szary}{HTML}{7a7a7a}

\tikzstyle{kwadrat}=[rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, thin, black,top color=white, bottom color=niebieski, draw=szary, text= black, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm, drop shadow, text width = 2.5cm, text badly centered, inner ysep=-2pt, ]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
{\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
 \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat,](m1){\tiny d};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m1] (p1){\tiny c};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p1] (k1) {\tiny b};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=k1] (a1) {\tiny a};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \vspace{10pt}

 {\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
 \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat, below of=m1](m2){\tiny D};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m2] (p2){\tiny C};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p2] (k2) {\tiny THE PROBLEM IS HERE TOO MUCH SPACE BETWEEN LINES OF TEXT};
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{10pt}

 {\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
  \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat,](m1){\tiny A};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m1] (p1){\tiny B};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p1] (k1) {\tiny C};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=k1] (a1) {\tiny D};
  \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You can say `\parbox{2.5cm}{\tiny ...}`, but three lines won't fit anyway. Maybe with `\fontsize{4}{5}\selectfont` instead of `\tiny`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}%
\mode<presentation>%
{
\usetheme{Madrid}%
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\makeatletter
   \newcommand\myFont{\@setfontsize\myFont{6pt}{7}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  arrows,%
  shapes.misc,%
  shapes.arrows,%
  positioning,% wg. " of "
  scopes,%
  decorations.pathmorphing,%
  shadows%
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\title[Example]%
{\textbf{How to get better leading in node}} %
\subtitle{}%
\author[]%
{Foo Bar}%
\institute[of Beamer]%
{ 
%
}
\date[\today]%
{}%

\subject{Talks}%

\definecolor{niebieski}{HTML}{aac9cb}
\definecolor{szary}{HTML}{7a7a7a}

\tikzstyle{kwadrat}=[rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, thin, black,top color=white, bottom color=niebieski, draw=szary, text= black, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm, drop shadow, text width = 2.5cm, text badly centered, inner ysep=-2pt, ]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
{\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
 \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat,](m1){\tiny d};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m1] (p1){\tiny c};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p1] (k1) {\tiny b};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=k1] (a1) {\tiny a};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \vspace{10pt}

 {\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
 \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat, below of=m1](m2){\tiny D};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m2] (p2){\tiny C};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p2] (k2) {\parbox{2.5cm}{\tiny SOME TEXT HERE SPANNING TWO LINES}};
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{10pt}

 {\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
  \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat,](m1){\tiny A};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m1] (p1){\tiny B};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p1] (k1) {\tiny C};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=k1] (a1) {\tiny D};
  \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

As **egreg** mentioned in his comment, instead of `\tiny`, you can use a smaller font size using `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}%
\mode<presentation>%
{
\usetheme{Madrid}%
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\makeatletter
   \newcommand\myFont{\@setfontsize\myFont{6pt}{7}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  arrows,%
  shapes.misc,%
  shapes.arrows,%
  positioning,% wg. " of "
  scopes,%
  decorations.pathmorphing,%
  shadows%
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\title[Example]%
{\textbf{How to get better leading in node}} %
\subtitle{}%
\author[]%
{Foo Bar}%
\institute[of Beamer]%
{ 
%
}
\date[\today]%
{}%

\subject{Talks}%

\definecolor{niebieski}{HTML}{aac9cb}
\definecolor{szary}{HTML}{7a7a7a}

\tikzstyle{kwadrat}=[rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, thin, black,top color=white, bottom color=niebieski, draw=szary, text= black, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm, drop shadow, text width = 2.5cm, text badly centered, inner ysep=-2pt, ]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
{\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
 \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat,](m1){\tiny d};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m1] (p1){\tiny c};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p1] (k1) {\tiny b};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=k1] (a1) {\tiny a};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \vspace{10pt}

 {\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
 \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat, below of=m1](m2){\tiny D};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m2] (p2){\tiny C};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p2] (k2) {\parbox{2.5cm}{\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont\centering SOME TEXT HERE SPANNING THREE LINES OF TEXT JUST FOR THIS SHORT EXAMPLE}};
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{10pt}

 {\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
  \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat,](m1){\tiny A};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m1] (p1){\tiny B};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p1] (k1) {\tiny C};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=k1] (a1) {\tiny D};
  \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you can also consider increasing a little the height of the nodes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}%
\mode<presentation>%
{
\usetheme{Madrid}%
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\makeatletter
   \newcommand\myFont{\@setfontsize\myFont{6pt}{7}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  arrows,%
  shapes.misc,%
  shapes.arrows,%
  positioning,% wg. " of "
  scopes,%
  decorations.pathmorphing,%
  shadows%
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 

\title[Example]%
{\textbf{How to get better leading in node}} %
\subtitle{}%
\author[]%
{Foo Bar}%
\institute[of Beamer]%
{ 
%
}
\date[\today]%
{}%

\subject{Talks}%

\definecolor{niebieski}{HTML}{aac9cb}
\definecolor{szary}{HTML}{7a7a7a}

\tikzstyle{kwadrat}=[rectangle, rounded corners=2pt, thin, black,top color=white, bottom color=niebieski, draw=szary, text= black, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=0.6cm, drop shadow, text width = 2.5cm, text badly centered, inner ysep=-2pt, ]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
{\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
 \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat,](m1){\tiny d};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m1] (p1){\tiny c};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p1] (k1) {\tiny b};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=k1] (a1) {\tiny a};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \vspace{10pt}

 {\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
 \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat, below of=m1](m2){\tiny D};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m2] (p2){\tiny C};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p2] (k2) {\parbox{2.5cm}{\fontsize{4}{5}\selectfont\centering SOME TEXT HERE SPANNING THREE LINES OF TEXT JUST FOR THIS SHORT EXAMPLE}};
     \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{10pt}

 {\myFont \textbf{SOME TEXT}}
  \vspace{2pt}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm]
     \node[kwadrat,](m1){\tiny A};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=m1] (p1){\tiny B};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=p1] (k1) {\tiny C};
     \node[kwadrat, right of=k1] (a1) {\tiny D};
  \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dosent work correct for long text [3 lines]. Each line must be next to another. As close as possible. \parbox leave space. What next then?

Comment: @DanielMiliński please see my updated answer.

Comment: @DanielMiliński new update.